# Java JSP custom taglib evaluation in a string

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I want to evaluate a `JSP` custom tag in a String from a controller method (not a JSP).

Say I have my `String`:

```
"<ex:Hello />"
```

And, after evaluation, I want to get the following `String`:

```
"Hello Custom Tag!"
```

(I use the tag example from: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_custom_tags.htm)

How can I do this by using `JSP` custom tags without crazy string parsing.

My root problem is that I get a string from a `API` with custom tags that I have to evaluate.

There are `two` ways to do this:

1. The first one is to evaluate a `JSP` twice. The first evaluation gets
   the string from the controller to the `JSP` and the second evaluates
   them. So far as I know this is impossible.
2. The second way is to evaluate the strings in the controller first
   before the `JSP` gets evaluated. I want to try the second way.

Thanks!

Comment: I find it hard to believe that this API expects you to parse tag invocations, unless it's intended to be called by code that *generates* JSP pages. In which case, that's probably your best solution: create a JSP that includes the string, with some delimiters so that you can parse it, then generate an internal request that executes that JSP. Alternatively, since tags are instantiable classes, you could parse the string, extract the tag calls, instantiate/configure the instance, then call `execute()` (or whatever it's called; it's been years since I've done this).

Comment: But, either approach is almost certainly the wrong thing to do.